# angularjs: best way to force certain link paths to reload

Tags: html, angularjs, routes

I'd like to be able to catch any link in my site that starts with "/@" and handle with a full browser reload.

Something like:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
$routeProvider.when("/@:id",
  # window.location.href = [the link's url]
  # all others are handled by typical controller/view
```

I have been able to solve the problem using an attribute/directive on an anchor tag, but I'd like to do this at the url routing level.

Comment: That's not really the answer to your question, but you could add `target="_self"` to your links as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19257277/2248275

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but you can set a parameter based on current time instead of the '/@' code

e.g.

```
<a href="/Customer/Edit/{{customer.id}}&refresh={{now}}">{{customer.Name}}</a>
```

where 'now' is set on $rootScope after each $routeChangeSuccess

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
$rootScope.now = Date.now();
});
```

This might be improved but it's working.

You might also have a look to [angularjs - refresh when clicked on link with actual url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267284/angularjs-refresh-when-clicked-on-link-with-actual-url/15795328#)