# Logout url in html5mode angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

So right now I have configured html5mode.

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

This is end of my middelware for express to support html5mode

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    if (!req.path.match('/calendar|/user|/create|/profile')) {
        return res.send(404);
    }
    res.render('home/index', {
        currentUser: req.user
    });
});
```

And all my urls are working good in Chrome and Firefox 3.6(which I'm using to test hashbang fallback).

My only issue is with the logout route.  My logout is a server interaction.  So I did this.

```
    $rootScope.logout = function () {
        window.location = '/logout';
    };
```

And made an ng-click to this function and that worked for logging out in Chrome.  How would I go about doing this in the hashbang fallback mode?  It's not working in Firefox 3.6.  Thanks!

Comment: You may try `$location.url('/logout')`

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  Doesn't work in or out of html5mode

Comment: Well, I think you may detect the browser to see whether it supports the pushState or not. If not then add the `#!` manually. :)

Comment: The logout url is a traditional url that needs to hit the server.  In this case this is not working.  All the client side routing is working, in html5mode and in older browsers.  Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use ng-click? Why not a direct link (i.e. href) to "/logout"?

Comment: Direct link is not working.  That's the whole point.  Angular client side routing is intercepting the /logout because I'm in html5mode.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried linking like so: <a href="/logout" target="_self">Logout</a>?

Comment: Thanks man.  If you post as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a target="_self" to the link like this:

```
<a href="/logout" target="_self">Logout</a>
```

AngularJS ignore links with a target attribute. This is documented here: [HTML link rewriting](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting) (search for _self).