# how can I reload my angular page without using location.reload()?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

There seem to be two answers to this question:

```
    $scope.cancel = ->
      location.reload()
```

or:

```
    $scope.cancel = ->
      $route.reload()
```

The first works fine but it is a full GET and seems to be doing a lot more work than needed. The second doesn't seem to work at all -- I can see it hitting the reload method and queuing up the `updateRoute` function with `this.$$asyncQueue.push(expr)` but the reload doesn't happen. Can I force `$route.reload` to work?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

[Related SO post, but answer doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267284/angularjs-refresh-when-clicked-on-link-with-actual-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried $location.path(..) ?
[angular $location service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

```
 # this code handles the funky url that gets generated and keeps 
 #    the funk to a minimum
 # moment is a js library for dealing with time
 # typical url looks like: 
 # http://192.168.101.111:3001/#/admin/user/edit/M6E8WANLIAF%231376602267119
 # moment tag is after %23 and angular seems to deal with it just fine
    $scope.cancel = ->
      if (/#/.test($location.$$path))
        $location.path($location.$$path.replace(/#.*/, "##{moment()}"))
      else
        $location.path($location.$$path += "#" + moment());
```

Comment: Kinda, I just tried `$location.$$path += "#" + moment();` which produced "/admin/user/edit/U4B7O08P4LG#1376601341118" and then `route.reload` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I believe you don't need to do a route.reload if you just try a $location.path($location.path()+'#'+moment()), just a suggestion, might help

Comment: Looks like that did it. I'll put my answer in your answer. Feel free to edit it.