# How to have angular reload the active state?

Tags: angularjs, routes, state, reload

When I'm on a `state/route` say `#/users` and I click on a link that goes the the **exact** same state/route, it does nothing, I would like to have this state reload.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267284/angularjs-refresh-when-clicked-on-link-with-actual-url

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router you can user

```
$state.reload()
```